# Effect of longer key on DES security

Tags: des, key-size

I am reading a book on cryptography and the author states that one of the complaints of the research community was that DES key length was chosen to be too short.

I am trying to depict how DES would look like if the key was 128 bits instead of 56(64) and why it would be more secure. I managed to express some ideas, but I am not sure how to evaluate them.

1. **Expansion Permutation Effect:** If the key length used after Expansion Permutation E(R-1) is increased, than R-1 expands to more bits (and then hashes
   with longer subkey). This means that the diffusion is greater.
2. **Less overlapping in key scheduling:** Key length also affects how key scheduling is executed. A longer key
   length means that shifts can be greater but I am not sure how this
   affects security.

I'd love to hear an authoritative answer to my pondering. Have I missed something?

Feistel network:
[image: Feistel network:]

Key schedule
[image: Key schedule]

In 4 rounds, a single left shift occures, in other 12, 2 bits are shifted in each of the key halfs.

Comment: Hi sanjihan, the size of the key space itself is already a major issue. 2^56 different keys is by far too small given todays hardware. These concerns were what mainly lead to 3DES coming up and then the standardization of AES. However, I can not answer your question on how DES would have to look like if were to increase the key length. That's why I only post this as a comment. I hope it helps you nevertheless.

Comment: Describe your actual key schedule so that we can talk about how the attack's can work there.  Also, DES block size is small for most of the applications. See sweet32.info

Comment: I've added some pictures of how DES works.

Comment: Look up Lucifer—it was the name of the predecessor to DES at IBM before NSA deliberately sabotaged the design by truncating what was a 128-bit key down to 56 bits.  (There were a few different versions of Lucifer, since it was never formalized as a standard before being sabotaged.)

Comment: The Key Schedule for Lucifer and DES aren't related. NSA contributed to PC2.